# Not receiving Windows 10 updates

Tags: windows-10-mobile, update, insider-preview, nokia-lumia-720

I have Nokia Lumia 720. I am a Windows Insider on Windows 10(PC) for new using features & bug fixes(mostly on Bash Shell). Of course we don't have official public Windows 10 update for Lumia 720. I got it with insider app now that I have got Windows 10 update, I've uninstalled Insider and I no more get Windows 10 updates on my Windows Phone. Is that the reason I don't receive updates from setting > Updates?

Should I install Insider app again to get updates? How do I check the current build on my device? What's the next best build available? What should I choose: Fast or Slow updates?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There are no official builds for 512 mb ram phones, if you want 10 on your phone, you'll have to go with insider builds.

You'll only get threshold builds nd it can be obtained using **Release preview** ring. You'll not get any updates if you register as fast/slow insider.

The latest threshold build is 10586.456, its stable that preceding builds!